# Wordpress wp_trash_post hooks not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, hook

This applies to all the hooks associated with `wp_trash_post()`; `pre_trash_post`, `wp_trash_post`, `trashed_post` and the transition hooks, eg `publish_to_trash`. All behave in exactly the same way.

I have a piece of code to run on this hook;

```
function to_fire_on_hook($post_id) {

 ... do stuff

// Get the slug of the $post_id above - the post being trashed

    $slug = $post->post_name;

... more stuff that then
    do_something(..., $slug, ...);

    // doesn't work unless I put 
    die; //here
   
  }
}

add_action('wp_trashed_post', 'to_fire_on_hook');
```

if I put `die` in the function, it completes OK, if I remove it the function doesn't complete.

I thought it might be to do with the fact that putting the post in the trash appends `_trash` to its name but appending that to `$slug` doesn't make any difference (neither does using the post ID).

I have swapped out all variables for static values and the result is the same. If the execution stops with `die` or `wp_die()` the last function executes, if not it doesn't.

Using `echo` statements before the `die` shows the correct values.

Any light on what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: You are using `wp_trashed_post` instead of `wp_trash_post` **ed** is extra in your hook name. then `$post` is not defined in the code from which you're trying to get the slug.

Comment: @VijayHardaha you wouldn't believe the amount of time I've spent over that "ed" ;-) Thank you very much. (incidentally the $post is picked up further along the line)